# Calling two functions using Ajax options

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to run two functions using AjaxOptions upon form submission. However, only one function is being called. I would like both of them to run when the form is submitted.

here is my ajax options:

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddDiagnosis", "Student",

            new AjaxOptions(){
                OnSuccess = "HandleAddDiagnosisCode",
                OnBegin = "return ValidateAddStudentDiagnosisCode(" + @studentId + ")"

            }, new
            {
                id = "AddStudentDiagnosis-" + @studentId,
                name = "AddStudentDiagnosis-" + @studentId
            }
            ))
        {
```

and these are the functions:

```
function ValidateAddStudentDiagnosisCode(id) {   
    var valid = true;    
    var msg = "";
    var errorPanel = $('#modal-AddStudentDiagnosis-ErrorPanel');
    PopulateErrorMessage(errorPanel, msg);
    errorPanel.hide();
    var diagCode = $('#modal-AddStudentDiagnosis_DiagCode-' + id).val();

    if (diagCode === "") {
        msg = "You must select a diagnosis code";
        valid = false;
    }
    var sequence = $('#modal-AddStudentDiagnosis_Sequence-' + id).val();
    if (sequence === "") {
        msg = "You must select a sequence";
        valid = false;        
    }
    if (valid == false) {
        PopulateErrorMessage(errorPanel, msg);      
    }    
    return valid;
}

    function HandleAddDiagnosisCode(e) {   
        alert('test');
        var errorPanel = $('#modal-AddStudentDiagnosis-ErrorPanel');
        PopulateErrorMessage(errorPanel, '');
        var errorMessage = e.ErrorMessage;
        if (errorMessage.length > 0) {
            PopulateErrorPanel(errorPanel, errorMessage);
        }
        else {
            ClearModal();        
            // Reload the document view
            $('#detailPanel').fadeOut(500, function () {
                $(this).empty();
            }).fadeIn(250, function () {
                $(this).html(e.Html);
                BindDocumentEdit();
                BindDataTable();
                BindDatePickers();            
            });
        }
```

my test alert is not called when the form is submitted.

Comment: When do you want to run ? Before the ajax call ? after the ajax call ?

Comment: After, I want the validate form to run, and then if that returns valid, I want the handle function to run.

Comment: So you want to call the validate function before making the ajax call and stop the ajax call if it is not valid and want to call the second function after ajax call is done (after receiving the response from server) ??

Comment: Try my answer ;)

Comment: yes that is correct @Shyju

Comment: So what is the problem ? what is not woking ? try `function ValidateAddStudentDiagnosisCode(id) {   
            alert('before sending');
            return true;
        }
        function HandleAddDiagnosisCode(e) {   
                alert('test');
               
         }` and slowly add your code to the methods, then you will know which part is giving you the trouble

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your function calls using anonymous function like this:

```
@using (@Ajax.BeginForm("AddDiagnosis", "Student", new AjaxOptions
    {
        OnSuccess = "new function(){func1(xhr); func2();}"
    })
```

Comment: I tried this, and it broke the code. when I tried to put both functions in i got an error saying the namespace was undefined... any ideas?